# Android, How to check wheather IntentService running in command?

Tags: android, terminal, command, intentservice, dumpsys

My app has several Activities and Services and one intent service, when I use

```
dumpsys activity | grep My.App.Name
```

I can see my others services and activity in the terminal but I can't see my IntentService even it is already running in my app.

```
        public class MyIntentService extends IntentService
        {   
           public MyIntentService()
           {
             super("MyIntentService");       
           }

           @Override
           protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
           {              
             t1.start();           
           }


        Thread t1 = new Thread()
         {

           public void run()
           {
             ......................
           }
         }
     }
```

In my Manifest file it is defined as:

```
        <service
        android:name=".MyIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I want to check if this IntentService is running or not from command, any help please?

Comment: `onHandleIntent` runs already on a background thread

Comment: But how to see it on command?

Comment: For example I can see my main activity "MyApp.Name/.MainActivity" and some other services but I can't see "MyApp.Name/.MyIntentService" when I use "dampsys"?

Comment: I think the system kills it after it finishes to accomplish its task, and creates a new instance when you call startservice, but honestly I am no entirely sure...

Comment: This intent service has infinity while loop and it should continue working and, I know it is working from the results that continues printed out inside this service.

Comment: well I mean.. what I am seeing it just the fact that it is spawning  another thread